# com.facebook.react:react-native:+ dependency doesn't compile in Android Studio on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I went through the react-native setup for [windows](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), getting through the following (and installing Android Studio) with no issues.

```
choco install nodejs.install
choco install python2
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then I opened the [android part](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-datetime/tree/master/android) of this react-native datetime package in Android Studio.

However when I tried to clean and rebuild I get an error when it gets to the [react-native compile dependency](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-datetime/blob/master/android/build.gradle#L24)

```
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
```

suggesting it can't find an installed react-native.

The full error is:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:react-native:+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:react-native are available.
 Searched in the following locations:
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/
     file:/C:/Users/funkyeah/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/C:/Users/funkyeah/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/
     file:/C:/Users/funkyeah/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/C:/Users/funkyeah/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified
```

I did notice that the `package.json` of the package did not have react-native as a dependency, or any dependencies at all... should all react-native packages have a react-native as a dependency in the root package.json?

Answer (score 2):

At the time I was facing this issue, there was an issue with jcenter. I resolved it by replacing **jcenter()** with **gradlePluginPortal()**. Go to the project-level build.gradle file and please make the below changes.

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            //jcenter() --> comment this 
            gradlePluginPortal() --> add this. 
        }
    }
  allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            gradlePluginPortal() --> add this
           //jcenter() --> comment this
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem with a node module I'm trying to build.  It looks like you need to tell gradle where to look:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    ...
}
```

Another possible method to call inside of repositories is `mavenCentral()`. I think `jcenter()` points to the newer location.

Answer (score -1):

Here small change to your dependency  just replace it

`compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'`
To

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile project(":react-native-fbsdk")
}
```

Comment: that just resulted in a different error: "Project with path ':react-native-fbsdk' could not be found in the root project 'android' " ... also the react-native-datetime package is not my package but someone elses that works as-is... I just want to make some changes to the android portion of it and am trying to figure out how to properly import it into android-studio to do so